# Ruby on Rails - Share one method with 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following module

```
module SharedMethods

    # Class method
    module ClassMethods

        #
        # Remove white space from end of strings
        def remove_whitespace
            self.attributes.each do |key,value|
                if value.kind_of?(String) && !value.blank?
                    write_attribute key, value.strip
                end
            end
        end


    end

    #
    #
    def self.included(base)
        base.extend(ClassMethods)
    end

end
```

and I am using it in my models like

```
include SharedMethods
before_validation :remove_whitespace
```

However whenever I submit the form I get a  "undefined method `remove_whitespace'" message

What can I do to correct this error?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `:remove_whitespace` must be an instance method, not a class method.

```
module SharedMethods

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
  end

  module InstanceMethods

    # Remove white space from end of strings
    def remove_whitespace
      self.attributes.each do |key,value|
        if value.kind_of(String) && !value.blank?
          write_attribute key, value.strip
        end
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Unless you need the module to provide both class and instance methods, you can also skip the usage of self.included and simplify your module in this way:

```
module SharedMethods

  # Remove white space from end of strings
  def remove_whitespace
    self.attributes.each do |key,value|
      if value.kind_of(String) && !value.blank?
        write_attribute key, value.strip
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: There will be other methods in this module so would like to stay with using self.included

doing the above now throws this error 
private method `include' called for #<Class:0x27416c8>

/Users/andy/rails_apps/test_app/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:1964:in `method_missing'
/Users/andy/rails_apps/test_app/lib/shared_methods.rb:7:in `included'

Comment: private error is coming from base.include.  Most direct way around is to work through send: `base.__send__(:include, InstanceMethods)`

Comment: You're right. You should either use send(:include, Module) or class_eval { include Module }.

Comment: @justin whoa! You should never need to include InstanceMethods in a module. That's the point of a module. Just put the methods in the module body and include it ;)

Comment: Yehuda that's an interesting point. However, it seems the most part of Rails core modules/plugins uses this architecture. Are you suggesting to avoid the ClassMethods/InstanceMethods convention? I personally find it more readable and intuitive.